# Typesafe higher order React component over class components and stateless functional components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to write a higher order component to check whether a user is authenticated.  I'm using React 15.5.4 and @types/react 15.0.21, and my (simplified) code looks as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface IAuthProps {
  authenticated: boolean
}

function authenticated1<Props extends Object>(wrapped: React.ComponentClass<Props> | React.SFC<Props>):
  React.SFC<Props & IAuthProps> {
  return (props: Props & IAuthProps): React.ReactElement<any> => {
    if (props.authenticated) {
      return React.createElement(wrapped, props);
    } else {
      return <h1>Unauthorized!</h1>
    }
  }
}
```

However, compilation fails in the call to `createElement`:

```
TS2345:Argument of type 'ComponentClass<Props> | StatelessComponent<Props>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentClass<Props>'.
  Type 'StatelessComponent<Props>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Props>'.
    Type 'StatelessComponent<Props>' provides no match for the signature 'new (props?: Props | undefined, context?: any): Component<Props, ComponentState>'
```

The error is no surprised since `@types/react` declares `React.createElement` as an overloaded function, and Typescript [can't resolve overloads with union types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107).

However `@types/react` provides an eligible overload for each type in the union (`SFCEelement` inherits `ReactElement` so the return types are compatible):

```
function createElement<P>(
    type: ComponentClass<P>,
    props?: Attributes & P,
    ...children: ReactNode[]): ReactElement<P>;

function createElement<P>(
    type: SFC<P>,
    props?: Attributes & P,
    ...children: ReactNode[]): SFCElement<P>;
```

To make the code compile I'd just need to force Typescript to consider either overload for the corresponding branch in the union type, but I have no idea how to do that.

**How can I discriminate between `ComponentClass` and `SFC` to make Typescript pick the corresponding overload for type checking?**

---

PS: Currently I'm just forcing it to pick the first overload by passing `wrapped as React.ComponentClass<Props>` which is safe since both overloads call out to the same runtime function which accepts both argument types, but I'd rather not like to "cheat" here, and instead have the type system guarantee the safety.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's currently not possible to do that because it requires changing the type definitons.

To use Type Guards feature which allows to narrow down the type of an object we need to extend a little the definitions.

```
interface StatelessComponent<P> {
    (props: P & { children?: ReactNode }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>;
    type: 'StatelessComponent'; // NEW ONE
    propTypes?: ValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}

interface ComponentClass<P> {
    new (props?: P, context?: any): Component<P, ComponentState>;
    type: 'ComponentClass'; // NEW ONE
    propTypes?: ValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    childContextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}
```

And then we would be able to do something like that

```
function createElementWrapper<Props extends Object>(wrapped: React.ComponentClass<Props> | React.SFC<Props>, props: any) {
  if (wrapped.type === "StatelessComponent") {
    return React.createElement(wrapped, props); // wrapped is a StatelessComponent
  } else {
    return React.createElement(wrapped, props); // wrapped is a ComponentClass
  }
}
```

It's might be a good idea to create an issue regarding this problem on the definitelytyped repository